# "Числовая" этимология

Tags: этимология

Предлагаю филологическому сообществу задачи, которые я придумала сама (если они есть еще где-то в источниках, заранее прошу прощения, я математик и не специалист в этимологии). Надеюсь, мои решения окажутся правильными (но о них - потом).

1. Что означало, по-вашему, старое русское слово **полтретья**? Для решения задачи найдите современное слово, близкое по звучанию. А откуда произошло слово **полтора**?
2. Слово **сугубо** в наше время обычно понимается как синоним слов *очень*, *особенно*. А как вы думаете, что означало это слово раньше? Две цитаты:
   *Злосчастие меня преследует: вчера скончался дед мой, а сегодня испустила дух моя бабка! Для чего и надел я сугубый траур.* 
       (“Выдержки из записок моего деда” Козьмы Пруткова)
   *Счастлив муж доброй жены и число дней его сугубое...* (
   “Книга премудрости Иисуса, сына Сирахова”)

И еще одно задание, не этимологическое, но про числа
3. В английском языке после числительных (кроме 1) слова стоят во множественном числе: *one book*, но *two books*, *three books*, … В татарском языке, наоборот, в единственном числе: *бер китап*, *ике китап*, *өч китап*. А в русском? В каком числе стоит существительное в словосочетании "три книги"?

Поледнее задание, конечно, простое, его можно предлагать школьникам младших классов.

**Добавление**. Филологи правильно ответили на вопрос, в том смысле, что *дали ответ*. Хотя для меня ценность этих задач другая: показать рассуждение, т.е. то, как можно догадаться до ответа, не будучи специалистом и используя в основном материал самой задачи.

Кстати, я поискала *полтретья* в Гугле, так вот, люди говорят, что это 1/6 ! И так же заявляют все ученики, когда им дашь эту задачу! А потом, с моей подсказки, начинаются "Изыскания"

Думаю, стоит еще "порешать" задачу, чтобы найти не готовые ответы, а логичные объяснения к ним.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

~1. Это хорошо известный вопрос. Полтретья - 2.5 Полтора - от "полвторая".

~2. Сугубо - вдвойне. Сравните - усугубить.
"А что очки товарищу разбили, Так то портвейном усугубили." (В. Высоцкий)
К сожалению, этимология мне не очень понятна.

~3. А вот этот вопрос совсем не простой. Школьникам - рано. Это рефлекс т.н. двойственного числа в русском. Сначала оно использовалось только для парных предметов, потом - любых двух. Еще позже - для двух, трёх и четырёх предметов. И только после отмирания в русском двойственного числа как грамматической реалии это "двойственное число" совпало с родительным единственного.

ЗЫ Привет математикам. По-хорошему мне надо за них выступать. У филологов я чувствую себя легионером. ;)

Comment: Конечно, этимология слов была известна, но я попыталась оформить их в виде задач для школьников. Например, подобрала цитаты. Т.е. идея в том, чтобы найти ответ не из источников (где он, кончечно, есть, не сама же я придумала слова), а "в автономном плавании". Задачи на смекалку.
Про третий вопрос я не имела в виду, что надо заходить так далеко в историю. Я подчеркнула, что вопрос не этимологический. Просто, если не задуматься, обычный человек скажет, что книги - это множественное число. И только сравнив с другими словами - что это род. падеж единственного (в современном понимании).

Comment: ЗЫ Да, это заметно (что перейти, а не что легионер).

Comment: Ср. усугубить + Высоцкий не дают никакого представления о "вдвойне" и вообще о числовом подтексте в этом слове!

Answer (score 2):

> Продавец халвы вместо того, чтобы расхваливать товар, кричит: "О Аллах, благодарю тебя за неисчислимость живущих на свете". Почему?

Всегда найдется идиот, который купит это. Ходжа Насреддин.

Comment: Да, так. Только продавец еще уточнил, что его халва - горькая, и любой, попробовавший ее, никогда больше не купит.

Comment: Конечно. я не решила Вашей задачи. Просто перечитывала истории о Ходже Насреддине. Многие из них годятся для подобных задач.

Comment: Так она и была построена. из истории. Только там, кажется, не упонимался Ходжа.

Answer (score 1):

По п.2. Слово *СУГУБО* имеет тот же корень, что и губить. *Губити* означало 'заставлять гнуться, сгибаться, гибнуть', 'приводить к гибели, потере'. Отсюда же *губа* 'изгиб', *пагуба, гибель*. Скорее всего СУГУБЫЙ означало 'гнутый, согнутый'(например, вдвое) (Цыганенко Г.П.Этимологический словарьрусского языка. Киев, 1989. Статья "Губить"). Как произошло такое разительное изменение в значении? Может кто-то еще найдет источники.
По п.1 и п.3 - ответы исчерпывающие.

Comment: Какое изменение Вы имеете в виду: из _гнуть_ во _вдвое_ или из _вдвойне_ в _очень_? Оба не так уж невозможны.

Comment: Нет, "сугубый" от "губть" это есть также и у Фасмера и у Преображенского. И этимологический ряд довольно полный, индоевропейского уровня. Но как это связано с "вдвойне, двойной" - не ясно. Хотя версия Цыгвненко не такая уж бессмысленная. Согнуть, перегнуть (лист, например) - удвоить толщину.

Answer (score 1):

Да, не имело смысла задавать такие задачи филологам. Если люди и так знают, что сугубо = вдвойне, то им не захочется это доказывать. Для простых же смертных эти задания являются поводом пошевелить мозгами. 
Я предполагала такие ответы.
 1. Составить таблицу: полтретья - ? - полтретьего - 2,5 часа, под этим: ? - 1,5 - полвторого - 1,5 часа, откуда все и следует
 2. Вторая цитата показывает, что слово связано с числом, а первая - что с числом 2 (герой Пруткова надел два черных камзола)
 3. Если не углубляться в историю языка, надо просто взять слово другого склонения.

Comment: Я, как уже говорил, совсем не филолог. По образованию - прикладной математик, по профессии - программист широкого профиля. Правда весьма древний уже. Но именно это даёт мне некоторое моральное право прокомментировать.

Comment: ~0. Не стоит переносить математическое понятие о доказательности на лингвистику. "Люди" вполне могли не знать что такое *сугубо*. Но за ответом никто из уважающих себя лингвистов не станет лезть в собственные домыслы, если он, этот ответ, есть в любом профильном словаре. И слава Богу, иначе лингвистический мир превратился бы в сборище доморощенных задорновых (не к ночи будь помянут), выводящих богатыря от "тырить Бога", а этрусков - от "это русские". Филология - это прежде всего работа с источниками, а не с голой логикой. Как математик математику говорю.

Comment: ~1. Таблица ваша излишняя. Коли вы привели в условии "полтора", то всякий, кто хоть раз задумывался над эти словом поймет, откуда ветер дует.  
  
~2. Из цитат не очень понятна ваша мысли о числе и тем более - о числе два. Максимум до чего можно дойти, не забираясь в дебри собственных химер - что сугубый означает "усиленный".

~3. Если "не углубляться в историю", то вопрос бессодержателен. Про якобы родительный падеж дети узнают классе в третьем, если не раньше. И задают его постоянно в той или иной форме. Даже здесь, на этом ресурсе он уже мелькал в числе первых пятисот вопросов.

Comment: Ладно, закроем дискуссию. Оценочные высказывания всегда субъективны. Мои задачи не относятся к лингвистике (где нужны другие методы), скорее к "эвристике" или тренировке сообразительности.  
Насчет излишнести таблицы - Вы не поверите, но никто из школьников не мог понять "откуда ветер дует" даже при слове "полтора", и убедить их, что ответ не 1/6, было довольно трудно.  
Почему "сугубый" - усиленный, если "число дней сугубое" -прямо говорится о числе? А в первой цитате - 2 смерти. Знаете, эту задачу как раз решали.  
Про "Книги" - просто пустячок, т.к. не задумываясь говорят "множественное"

Comment: Вы просто слишком умный для этих задач, вот они Вам и не интересны. Тогда, может, решите еще одну (уже чисто эвристическую)? Ее пока никто не решил.  
Продавец халвы, вместо того, чтобы расхваливать товар, кричит "О Аллах, благодарю тебя за неисчислимость живущих на свете". Почему?  
Указание. Ответ "для рекламы" - неверный (по крайней мере - неполный)

Comment: Школьники какого класса были?

Что до эвристических задач, то как вы понимаете, у них нет однозначного ответа. Поэтому разгадывать их бывает довольно скучно. 
Может время намаза у него. А может он в каждом живущем видит потенциального покупателя. Или просто винтик у него сломался, пластинку зациклило.  И никто не докажет, что один ответ хуже другого.  
Хотя вернее всего он начитался новомодных рекламных теорий. Ибо известно, что для рекламы не так важно, что говорить, важно - как и когда.

Comment: Насчет "слишком умный"... Не думаю. Дело не в сложности. Просто есть определённые традиции - не побоюсь сказать "субкультура" - такого типа задач. В каждой области она своя. Не надо со своим уставом в чужой монастырь лезть. Вы про "глокую куздру" что-нибудь слышали? Вот это пример формализаованной задачи для лингвистов.   

А если задачу на логику (не путать с математической проблемой) никто не решил, то тем хуже для задачи.

Да, вот ещё вариант про продавца халвы. Он может говорить всё, что угодно, если к нему  и так очередь стоит.

Comment: 1. Школьники были старших классов + студенты.  
2. Кому что скучно - дело личное. Мне нравится, когда ответ не однозначный.  
3. Все ответы про халву - явно "не дотягивают". Но раз Вам не интересно, не буду говорить ответ (если его услышать - сразу ясно, что он "тот самый")
Дискуссию закрываю.

Comment: При всем уважении, просьба: переносите обсуждение в личку. Формат форума не предусматривает дискуссии.

Comment: Я свой e-mail опубликовала. Хорошо бы behemothus сделал то же. Я не прочь пообщаться

Answer (score 0):

Губы — изГиБы. Грибы также по сходству называют губами. Со(у)губить — сдвоить. Может, и ГиБрАЛТаР  того же корня. Погубить — принять губами через любовь — приняло смысл *гибнуть.* Есть синоним из семитских НК (никнуть, нике, Николай),  латыш. *nikns* — злой.

Answer (score -2):

Попытаюсь мыслить примитивно ,ибо на поприще высоких наук лавров не стяжала.Полтретя..По моему,кто-то перепутал каравай хлеба с циферблатом часов,кои появились на РУССИ не так давно.Если треть это один кусок делённого на 3 каравая,то полтретя это  =1/6 каравая.ПОЛТОРА-это полтъря=полтъри=половина трёх караваев.СУГУБО(как?),согубить(совместить губы),усугубить(совокупить,прибавить)СУГУБО=отдельно взятое с добавлением.ТРИ КНИГИ.Три-търы,а(ы)-это оные..множ.число.Это есть моё СУГУБО личное мнение.

Comment: Насчёт примитивности - это Вы в точку...

Comment: Ну со мной понятно я-ллюбитель.А вы поппробуйте объяснить происхождение слов:ГУБЕРНИЯ,ПОГУБИТЬ,ГУБЫ.

Comment: Я хочу обратить внимание, что слова губерния и губернатор очень напоминают английские слова govern, government, имеющие сходное, но не идентичное значение. Это должно натолкнуть на правильную мысль - поискать исходник в латыни. И, действительно, мы можем найти слово gubernius, которое вроде как означает "правитель"

Comment: Если в двух словах есть похожее сочетание букв, это еще не означает, что они имеют общее происхождение. Это я вам как математик говорю.  

Например, сочетаний согласная-гласная-согласная примерно 10х5х10 = 500 (считаем, что есть примерно 10 основных согласных и 5 гласных). Ну, а смыслов, конечно, гораздо больше! На каждый смысл своего индивидуального сочетания звуков не напасешься!  

Тем более странно выделять такие последовательности внутри слов, не учитывая морфологию и историческое развитие.  

Задорнов - он сатирик, ему можно пошутить. Нельзя же принимать его слова за чистую монету!

Comment: Губернатор от лат. gubernator. Это латинское слово означает:

1) рулевой или кормчий на судне, лодке

2) лидер, правитель

От лат. глагола guberno. Его этимология от древн.-греч. κυβερνάω (kubernaō) - управляю.

Предполагается, что слово *губерния* образовано от слова *губернатор* по аналогии со словами *император* (повелитель) - *империя*.

Ссылки на источники, если надо, могу дать.

Comment: А если попробовать пойти от обратного и взять за основу,что в родственных языках,как и в одном языке сочетание похожих по звуку морфем вовсе не случайно,а имеют под собой древнюю корневую основу?..пр.:жар(огонь),гар(огонь,гарь),кар(горелый,чёрный),колот(большой молот),кол(острая палка),колико(колличество),коло(колесо,круг),колка(круда камней)-имеют общий корень при разности значенй,но восходят к единому КЪЛ-(разбитый на части круглый камень-галька).,опять же это,только предположение любителя ..Задорнов здесь нипричём,хотя искренне уважаю,за то что разворошил ортодоксов.

Comment: Конечно, в родственных языках много неслучайного. Но много и случайного. Особенно в более поздних словах. Этимологическая догадка становится теорией только после больших, обширных и дотошных исследований. А отнюдь не любительских измышлений.  

И не надо Задорнова, попса и есть попса: пусть скандально - лишь бы заметили.

Comment: Коль уж "зацепили" ,поневоле Михаила Николаевича хочу в его защиту вам ответить,что врятли бы столь неглупый человек стал вещать на всю страну свою трактовку происхождения слов ,не имея под собой фундамент чьих-то-"больших,обширных и дотошных иследованний".

Comment: Его дело эстрадное: лишь бы заметили. Ради красного словца не пожалеет и отца. Да и вообще он юморист, я всегда воспринимала его слова как шуточные. Не мог же "умный человек" на самом деле считать всякое сочетание букв р+а в слове - осмысленным. 
Все это чушь собачья.